# Histogram in tableau

Tags: histogram, tableau-api, level-of-detail

In campaign analysis in a B2B set up I want to see how many days an organisation takes to convert from lead to customer after seeing a campaign in the form of an histogram.

Below is the sample data set where there are multiple lead underneath an organisation.

--For e.g  organisation abc has three leads- Bill, John and Sam. `Sam` is the last one to see the campaign amongst all three i.e. on 14/9/2020 on campaign date column and converted on same day. So for organisation abc it took 0 days to convert. *Here we are considering the last campaign date for a given organisation to create time to conversion view in the form of histogram*

--Organisation efg has two leads - Don and Harry. `Harry` is the last one to see the campaign on 18/9/2020 and converted on 19/9/2020. so organisation efg took 1 day to convert.

-- Similarly organisation pqr took 0 days to convert.

In filter I want to have **converted date** and **region** column so when sept is selected in converted date and US on region filter then a histogram view should come up couting 0 as 2 and 1 as 1.

[image]

I created a calculated field which capture the max of campaign date for a given organisation ID

if [campaign date] = {fixed[organization id]: MAX([campaign date])} then 1 else 0 END

But not able to create the view in the form of histogram.

Comment: So if i understood correctly, you want to create a histogram of number of days 'organisations' took as per criteria explained? Let me work it out.

Comment: Yes...it's at organisation level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nearly reached the solution..

**Step-1** create a T/F condition so that your criteria is met

```
[campaign date]={FIXED [org id]: max([campaign date])}
```

**Step-2** convert your field `days to convert` to both discreet and dimension.

**Step-3** you have a large number of vraiables under this column, you can also create bins of appropriate size (OPTIONAL but this will give a proper histogram look to your chart)

**Step-3** (I have not created bins so repeating step-3) add COUNTD(org id) to view, region filter to context, and `cond` filter to `TRUE` you'll get a view like this

[image]

if you'll proceed without creating bins, values of days to convert where no organisation meets the condition, will not show up, while if you have large distinct values in 'days to convert' creating bins will line them up neatly.

Comment: I create bins suggested by you as there are lots of values in days to convert column. To make it look like histogram I just had to increase the shape  of the bars. Glad that it came out that way. Thanks a ton